# Get StartDate and EndDate from Event Search Query

Tags: search, sharepoint-addin, search-results, sharepoint-search, add-ins

I am trying to develop a SharePoint Online Add-in.  I have a simple query that seems to get all of the Events the current user is authorized to see [1]:

```
var getEventsURL =
    "https://" + hostName + "/" + theSitePath +
    "/_api/search/query?" +
    "querytext='contenttype:Event'";
```

I run that query with a simple $.ajax call.  When the results come back, I get an array of rows in data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.ReleventResults.TableRows.results [2].  When I open one of these rows, I see yet another array of 48 values in Cells.results that contains all of the data fields for that row.

In column 3, I see the Title for the current Event.  Also in column 7, I see the Description [3].  That's very useful to me but I *also* need to find the StartDate and EndDate of the Event.  Unfortunately, I've looked all through the 48 returned values for the currently iterated Event and I can't find StartDate or EndDate anywhere.

After running a Search Query of the form
https://[serverName]/_api/search/query?queryText='contenttype:Event'; 
how do I find the DateTimes at which each Event begins and ends?

[1] - [Accessing list data in multiple site collections](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114329/accessing-list-data-in-multiple-site-collections) 
[2] - http://michaelsoriano.com/understanding-sharepoint-rest-api-part-1-selecting-items/ 
[3] - Column numbers are zero based

Comment: When I run "querytext='ContentClass:STS_ListItem_Events'" in the SharePoint Search Query Tool and click the "View all properties..." button in the Primary Results tab, I see the EndDateOWSDATE and EventDateOWSDATE properties I need, but I'm still not finding them in data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[index].Cells.results   where I would expect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the times the events started and stopped by referencing EndDateOWSDATE and EventDateOWSDATE via the selectProperties [1][2] query parameter.  My resulting query is:

```
var getEventsURL =
    "https://" + hostName + "/" + theSitePath +
    "/_api/search/query?" +
    "querytext='ContentClass:STS_ListItem_Events'" +
    "&selectProperties=" +
    "'Title,Description,EndDateOWSDATE,EventDateOWSDATE'";
```

I also made some changes to the SharePoint Search Schema similar to what is mentioned in [3] but I'm not 100% sure that was necessary.

[1] - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview#bk_SelectProperties 
[2] - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/3b2c39a3-8017-40c0-b866-e1efbf7104ad/how-do-i-query-all-the-managed-properties-available-for-search-results 
[3] - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/586d4eb5-e090-460e-892d-acfffd7ea489/calendars-fields-eventdate-and-enddate-does-not-appear-in-search-result